# Merge multiple trapezoids into one shape

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a project where the user can draw a shape by adding multiple trapezoids together. Currently it look like this :
[image: Current View]

But what I will like is remove / hide the lines inside the shape so that it makes a single shape :
[image: Result i want]

The shapes are created with 3 points {bsup; binf; h;} that represent the the length of the top line, the length of the bottom line, and the height of the shape

```
export const drawPolygonComplex = (ctx, values, inputValues, 
  distanceUnits, displayCote = true) => {
  const hCumul = calcHeight(values);
  const middleX = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
  const middleY = ctx.canvas.height / 2;
  const startY = middleY - hCumul / 2;

  let nbPiece = 0;
  let currentY = startY;

  if (inputValues.length) {
let cotes = [];
for (let key in values) {
  //#region attribution des valeurs pour placer les cotes
  let intKey = parseInt(key);

  let upperLongestValue = values[intKey].b_sup;
  let lowerLongestValue = values[intKey].b_inf;

  if (values.length > 1) {
    if (intKey == 0) {
      if (values[intKey + 1].b_sup) {
        lowerLongestValue =
          values[intKey].b_inf > values[intKey + 1].b_sup
            ? values[intKey].b_inf
            : values[intKey + 1].b_sup;
      }
    } else if (intKey == values.length - 1) {
      upperLongestValue =
        values[intKey].b_sup > values[intKey - 1].b_inf
          ? values[intKey].b_sup
          : values[intKey - 1].b_inf;
    } else {
      lowerLongestValue =
        values[intKey].b_inf > values[intKey + 1].b_sup
          ? values[intKey].b_inf
          : values[intKey + 1].b_sup;
      upperLongestValue =
        values[intKey].b_sup > values[intKey - 1].b_inf
          ? values[intKey].b_sup
          : values[intKey - 1].b_inf;
    }
  }

  let coteUpLeft = { x: middleX - upperLongestValue / 2, y: currentY };
  let coteUpRight = { x: middleX + upperLongestValue / 2, y: currentY };
  let coteDownLeft = { x: middleX - lowerLongestValue / 2, y: currentY + values[key].h };
  let coteDownRight = { x: middleX + lowerLongestValue / 2, y: currentY + values[key].h };
  //#endregion

  //Définir les coins
  let upLeft = { x: middleX - values[key].b_sup / 2, y: currentY };
  let upRight = { x: middleX + values[key].b_sup / 2, y: currentY };
  let downLeft = { x: middleX - values[key].b_inf / 2, y: currentY + values[key].h };
  let downRight = { x: middleX + values[key].b_inf / 2, y: currentY + values[key].h };

  //Dessiner la shape
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(HatchPattern(), 'repeat');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(upLeft.x, upLeft.y);
  ctx.lineTo(upRight.x, upRight.y);
  ctx.lineTo(downRight.x, downRight.y);
  ctx.lineTo(downLeft.x, downLeft.y);
  ctx.lineTo(upLeft.x, upLeft.y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  if (displayCote) {
    //Placer les cotes
    if (nbPiece % 2 == 0) {
      cotes[intKey + 1] = drawRightCote(
        ctx,
        coteUpRight.x,
        coteDownRight.x,
        coteUpRight.y,
        coteDownRight.y,
        distanceUnits,
        inputValues[key].h,
        1
      );
    } else {
      cotes[intKey + 1] = drawLeftCote(
        ctx,
        coteUpLeft.x,
        coteDownLeft.x,
        coteUpLeft.y,
        coteDownLeft.y,
        distanceUnits,
        inputValues[key].h,
        1
      );
    }
  }

  //Calcul des variables
  currentY += values[key].h;
  nbPiece++;

  if (displayCote) {
    //Cote du haut et du bas
    if (intKey == 0) {
      cotes[0] = drawUpperCote(
        ctx,
        coteUpLeft.x,
        coteUpRight.x,
        startY,
        distanceUnits,
        inputValues[key].b_sup,
        1
      );
    }
    if (intKey == values.length - 1) {
      cotes[values.length + 1] = drawLowerCote(
        ctx,
        coteDownLeft.x,
        coteDownRight.x,
        currentY,
        distanceUnits,
        inputValues[key].b_inf,
        1
      );
      //Cote hauteur
      drawLeftCote(
        ctx,
        middleX - values[0].b_sup / 2,
        coteDownLeft.x,
        startY,
        currentY,
        distanceUnits,
        calcHeight(inputValues),
        2
      );
    }
  }
}

return cotes;
```

}
};

Comment: You would have to draw all the shapes (with outlines) on another canvas. Then erase the lines where the shapes meet. Finally, grab the drawing data from that canvas and write it out to the main canvas.

Comment: How can I find where the lines meet ?

Answer (score 0):

You could figure out a way to trace the join-points and then clear them. First you need to locate where the shapes are joined together.

```js
const drawTrapezoid = (ctx, x, y, width, height, indent = 0) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + indent, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x - indent + width, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + height);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

const ctx = document.querySelector('#drawing').getContext('2d');

Object.assign(ctx.canvas, { width: 300, height: 300 });

const
  x = 20, y = 20,
  height = 160, width = 60,
  thickness = 6;

ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
drawTrapezoid(ctx, x, y, width, 20, -10);
ctx.strokeRect(x, y + 20, width, height - 40);
drawTrapezoid(ctx, x - 10, y + height - 20, width + 20, 20, 10);

const thickHalf = thickness / 2;
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(x + thickHalf, y - thickHalf + 20, width - thickness, thickness);
ctx.fillRect(x + thickHalf, y - thickHalf + height - 20, width - thickness, thickness);
```

```html
<canvas id="drawing"></canvas>
```

After you figure out where the points join, erase the lines. Instead of calling `fillRect` as seen in the latter part of the example above, call `clearRect`. Once you draw this shape on your separate canvas, grab the data and draw it to your main canvas.

```js
const drawTrapezoid = (ctx, x, y, width, height, indent = 0) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + indent, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x - indent + width, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + height);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

const ctx = document.querySelector('#drawing').getContext('2d');

Object.assign(ctx.canvas, { width: 300, height: 300 });

const
  x = 20, y = 20,
  height = 160, width = 60,
  thickness = 6;

ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
drawTrapezoid(ctx, x, y, width, 20, -10);
ctx.strokeRect(x, y + 20, width, height - 40);
drawTrapezoid(ctx, x - 10, y + height - 20, width + 20, 20, 10);

const thickHalf = thickness / 2;
ctx.clearRect(x + thickHalf, y - thickHalf + 20, width - thickness, thickness);
ctx.clearRect(x + thickHalf, y - thickHalf + height - 20, width - thickness, thickness);
```

```html
<canvas id="drawing"></canvas>
```

Drawing to the main canvas.

```js
const drawTrapezoid = (ctx, x, y, width, height, indent = 0) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + indent, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x - indent + width, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + height);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}

const ctx = document.querySelector('#drawing').getContext('2d');
const ctxTmp = document.querySelector('#tmp-drawing').getContext('2d');

Object.assign(ctx.canvas, { width: 300, height: 300 });
Object.assign(ctxTmp.canvas, { width: 300, height: 300 });

ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

const
  x = 20,
  y = 20,
  height = 160,
  width = 60,
  thickness = 6;

ctxTmp.lineWidth = thickness;
ctxTmp.strokeStyle = 'green';
drawTrapezoid(ctxTmp, x, y, width, 20, -10);
ctxTmp.strokeRect(x, y + 20, width, height - 40);
drawTrapezoid(ctxTmp, x - 10, y + height - 20, width + 20, 20, 10);

const thickHalf = thickness / 2;
ctxTmp.clearRect(x + thickHalf, y - thickHalf + 20, width - thickness, thickness);
ctxTmp.clearRect(x + thickHalf, y - thickHalf + height - 20, width - thickness, thickness);

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = ctxTmp.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
img.onload = () => ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

```css
#tmp-drawing { display: none; }
```

```html
<canvas id="drawing"></canvas>
<canvas id="tmp-drawing"></canvas>
```